# Any more ASP.NET MVC Frameworks like SharpArchitecture around?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Are there more ready-to-use MVC frameworks like SharpArchitecture?
For the small to medium projects I will be working on, SharpArch looks like an overkill to me. Plus I'm not yet very familiar with Domain Drive Development (but that is one thing I want to read about as soon as my time permits, it definitively sounds interesting)

Please link to all frameworks you know about. I don't have any requirements about the technology being used.

Comment: Currently I'm using LINQ to SQL, but I have had/still have some issues with it in combination with the ModelBinders in MVC, so NHibernate is one thing I would like to try in the future to see if it works out better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working on small to medium-size projects, then go with pure ASP.NET MVC - this already **is** a highly sophisticated framework.

You may consult a book like [ASP.NET MVC in Action](http://www.manning.com/palermo/) to understand how to best work with it and how to extend it, if necessary. Forget about other things for the moment, the learning curve would be very steep for you, and you most likely will end up in the middle of nowhere...

Thomas

Comment: I'm already working with ASP.NET MVC since a few months, I'm more looking for a framework/template to get me started faster on new projects, filled with some good practices as a guideline.

Comment: I see. AFAIK there is nothing comparable to SharpArch around. But I think you should definitely have a look at the 'ASP.NET MVC in Action' book. It also talks a lot about architecture and using different frameworks like e.g. NHibernate...